# Fallback route for MVC Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

Using asp.net core MVC application here. I have my areas defined and routing works as expected.

One thing i would like to do, is have a fallback route in case the area does not exist.

I have the following structure:

```
APP
-- Areas
   -- SharedArea
      -- Controllers
         -- LoginController
         -- UserController
         -- AnotherController
         -- AndSoOnController
   -- SomeArea1
      -- Controllers
         -- HomeController
   -- SomeArea2
      -- Controllers
         -- HomeController
         -- LoginController
```

My ultimate goal, is to have shared controllers that is being used as a fallback in the event that an area does not have the specified controller.

### Scenario 1

User currently browse `SomeArea1` and clicks on `Login`. There is no `LoginController` for `SomeArea1` and he gets directed to `SharedArea\Login`.

### Scenario 2

User currently browse `SomeArea2` and clicks on `Login`. There is a`LoginController` for `SomeArea2` and he gets directed to `SomeArea2\Login`.

How would one go about configuring your routes in the `Startup.cs` file?

My current route setup in `startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.DefaultHandler = areaRouter;
            routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

`areaRouter` is a custom implimentation for subdomain routing, you can view more here: [subdomain routing to areas](https://deadsith.github.io/2017/05/30/asp-net-core-mapping-areas-to-subdomains/)

Comment: For the two scenarios, show the `RouteConfig` setup for both areas.

Comment: added the current route configuration snippet

Answer (score 2):

> One thing i would like to do, is have a fallback route in case the
>   area does not exist.

Implement the base controllers for each area. In this way the controllers from those areas will use the `HandleAttribute` from the base controller. It's only 1 setting (one for each area in fact)

**Scenario1**: Create a base(shared) Controller in your area:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "sharedarea")]//see solution for next scenario
public class SharedAreaController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public login()
    {

    }
}
```

Derive SomeArea1 controllers from this controller:

```
public class HomeController : SharedAreaController 
{
    // actions for this controller
}
```

**Scenario2**: The place where you register you `CookieAuthentication` middleware, do this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/SomeArea2/login";
    o.AuthenticationScheme = "SomeArea2";
    //TODO: set other interesting properties if you want to
});
```

then On you controller/action, specify the authentication scheme like:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "SomeArea2")]
public IActionResult PageWhichNeedsArea2Auth()
{
    return Content("sth");
}
```

I hope to be helpful :)

Comment: Hey man, i did not implement your solution, but a base controller with overridable action results did the trick for me. I still have to add the controller in each area, but i can just choose to override the actions that i want to. Thanx for pointing me in the right direction